# | was unexpected at this time in Windows 7

Tags: batch-file

Here is my batch file

```
@echo off
set /a IPCOUNT=1
set IP_FILTER=^IPV4
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %%i in ('2^>nul ipconfig | findstr /i "!IP_FILTER!" | findstr /v "%"') do (
if "%%j" NEQ " 127.0.0.1" (
    echo    !IPCOUNT! %%j
    set IP_CHECK=%%j
    echo !IP_CHECK!>>"%REGULAR_IP_FILE%"
    set /a IPCOUNT+=1
)
)
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following error:

```
| was unexpected at this time.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Change those `|` to `^|`.

Comment: You are in a `for` loop, so you need to escape `|` with `^` => `^|` because `|` is executed in higher prio.

Comment: I am really confused, now. Why do you need that `findstr /V "%"`? Also, you seem to like to use regex (string `^IPV4`). Why don't you enable it in `findstr`?

Comment: You can't use `findstr /i "!IP_FILTER!" ` without having `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: When using `findstr /V "%"` to find `%`-symbols you need to actually write `findstr /V "%%"` in a batch file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed code is as follows:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "IPcount=1"
set "IP_filter=IPV4"

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('2^>nul ipconfig ^| findstr /IRC:"%IP_filter%"') do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        if not "%%B" == "127.0.0.1" (
            echo !IPcount! %%B
            (echo %%B)>>"%REGULAR_IP_FILE%"
            set /a "IPcount+=1"
        )
    )
)
```

- I have enabled [delayed expansion](//ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). It seems you use it in your file, but you haven't enabled it.
- It seems you want to find your IPv4 Address. I have modified your script to add a better way. Note that `IPv4` (case-*in*sensitive) is **not** in the start of the line. A space is in the start of the line, so I removed `^`, but kept regex enabled.
- Quote `set` variables and values: `set /a "var=value"`.

Comment: I would not have placed parenthesis around `/a` as OP might find it confusing, but regardless `set /a` does not require double quotes, in fact I would reccomend not using double quotes on `set /a`